# Is sum of digits of $3^{1000}$ divisible by $7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, divisibility, decimal-expansion

I'm working on a little exercise I found in my high school book (printed in 2007) which is pretty complicated.

Is the sum of digits of $3^{1000}$ a multiple of $7$?

Do you have any advice to solve this type of problem (without programming of course!)

PS :

We are a group of 3 french people working on it since 2007.

The sum calculated with Python is 2142, this number is a multiple of 7 BUT we want a mathematical answer.

All the results below are mathematically proved !!

$3^{1000}$ has 478 digits and the sum of digits of $3^{1000}$ can't be superior to 4302 (9*478).

This sum is a multiple of 3 and 9.

The last digits of $3^{1000}$ are 0001 (math proof not a result of a computer calculation).

The one who created this exercise doesn't know the answer.

Please help us with any clue!

---

Cross-posted at https://mathoverflow.net/q/282035/22954 on MathOverflow.

Comment: PS : We are a group of people working on it since 2007. till today, we don't have even a trail to follow...we know many things about this number but nothing helpful to answer to the question.

Comment: What is the name of the book

Comment: As for just getting the answer... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+digits+of+3%5E1000

Comment: @Lezraf Since $2007$? A computer program can do it fairly quickly - it's less than $500$ digits.

Comment: Of course, the first question is to ask if there's a pattern mod $7$.  Perhaps looking at $9^{500}$ instead.

Comment: it's the maths book of tunisian students of final year (baccalauréat)...

Comment: Yeah, we already calculated it with python, the sum is 2142 and it is a multiple of 7. But we are looking for a mathematical method...that question was in a maths book. the problem should be solved analytically!

Comment: Do you mind telling us in which book precisely was this problem? I doubt it was a high school book.

Comment: @Lezraf Maybe you are looking for a general way to find digit sum of $3^n$ modulo $7$?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel That's strange of you to say, given that the OP asks us to avoid computer, don't you think?

Comment: yes of course I'm sure, I was student in final year at that time !!

Comment: I'll try to find the book, but it's a hard "mission"

Comment: If you can help us just a little bit, it would be fantastic!!

Comment: @MichaelBurr I checked and did not see any obvious pattern in the sequence [sum of digits of $3^n$] modulo 7, nor with $9^n$.

Comment: 3P1000=1322070819480806636890455259752144365965422032752148167664920368226828597346704899540778313850608061963909777696872582355950954582100618911865342725257953674027620225198320803878014774228964841274390400117588618041128947815623094438061566173054086674490506178125480344405547054397038895817465368254916136220830268563778582290228416398307887896918556404084898937609373242171846359938695516765018940588109060426089671438864102814350385648747165832010614366132173102768902855220001, the sum is 2142. I have many other data if anyone need it.

Comment: @anderstood unfortunately...

Comment: this post has been deleted and I don't understand why..."one of the major and interesting track to explore is to try to give the most accurate possible upper and lower bounds of sum(3P1000).

We have today around 100 possible sums of S(3P1000)"

Comment: @Lezraf you should include some of your comments into you question. (say, the part about "working on it since 2007", "know the digit sum is 2142 and want a mathematical answer" and "even the teacher don't know the answer" ) This will make the question much more complete.

Comment: Let $a_i = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 6k +i $ th digit, then because $10^6 \equiv 1$(Fermat's little theorem), and $1 \equiv 1$, $10 \equiv 3$, $10^2 \equiv 2$, $10^3 \equiv 6$, $10^4 \equiv 4$, $10^5 \equiv 5$, we have $a_1 + 3a_2 + 2 a_3 + 6 a_4 + 4 a_5 + 5 a_6 \equiv 3^1000 = 4$. The question is what is $a_1 + a_2 +  a_3 +  a_4 +  a_5 +  a_6$. We can now shift the last digit to the top, such that $5 a_1 + a_2 + 3 a_3 + 2 a_4 + 6 a_5 + 4 a_6 \equiv 5 + (3^1000 - 1 ) / 10 = 6 $, etc. There will be an linear equation in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and we can solve each $a_i$.

Comment: $3^{1000}$ has a really simple ternary representation (base $3$). I wonder if that can be exploited.

Comment: Just spitballing: We have $3^{2n}=(-3)^{2n}$, and we have the tens-complement representation $-3=\bar97$, where the $9$s repeat infinitely to the left. So we want to know whether the sum of digits of $\bar97^{1000}$ is divisible by $7$. This may be look like a harder form of the problem, but maybe the coincidence of a $7$ appearing in two places will help, somehow?

Comment: I almost posted an incorrect answer based on the fact that for $ 3^{25}$ the sum of their digits is $63 = 7x9$. Too difficult for my means so I leave this problem.

Comment: @Piquito If this is not difficult, this won't be the first bounty I ever offer ;-p

Comment: "The sum calculated with Python is 2142" and "This sum has 478 digits and could be superior to 4302 (9*478)"  2142 is neither of those things.

Comment: @achille hui:I wonder which author of a high school book has proposed that problem. I think there is not a known mathematical tool that serves to relate the powers with the corresponding sums of digits.

Comment: @Piquito There are various types of problems. Some let the student familiar with the material, some test the student understanding of the ideas, there are also open-end problems which encourage students to discover and explore. This problem probably belongs to last category.

Comment: @fleablood thank you for you remark, I corrected my post. the number has 478 digits and the sum of digits can't be superior to 4302 (9*478).

Comment: Does anyone have a hint to know if the sum of $3^{1000}$ is divisible (or not divisible) by any number (2, 4 etc.) other than 3 or 9 ?

Comment: Is there a reason to expect there to be a short proof? Maybe this is just one of those things that can only be verified computationally.

Comment: @anecdote Unfortunately, the linear equations you suggest are all linearly dependent.

Comment: @Thomas, yes you are right. I worked out the equations and find at least 3 of them are redundant (meaning linearly dependence). In case anyone need it, the numerical result of the actual solution is $a_1 = 2$, $a_2 = 4$, $a_3 = 6$, $a_4 = 6$, $a_5 = 3$, $a_6 = 0$, the equations I suggest are not enough to get them.

Answer (score 3):

I am not answering the question but the post asks for clues so here it is a couple of ideas.

If $a_0,a_1,a_2, \cdots , a_{477} $ are the decimal digits of $3^{1000}$ then the numbers 
$$b_i=a_{6i}+a_{6i+1}\cdot 10+a_{6i+2}\cdot 10^2+a_{6i+3}\cdot 10^3+a_{6i+4}\cdot 10^4+a_{6i+5}\cdot 10^5$$
for $i=0,1,2,\cdots, 79$ are the digits of $3^{1000}$ in base $10^6$  ($80$ is the nearest integer above $477 \div 6$ so there are $80$ digits numbered $0,1,2,\cdots,79$)

In other words:
$$ 3^{1000} = b_0 + b_1 \cdot 10^6+ \cdots + b_{79} \cdot (10^6)^{79}$$

Now, if we resort to modular arithmetic we see that 
$$ 3^0=1, 3^1=3 , 3^2=2, 3^3=6, 3^4=4, 3^5=5, 3^6=1 $$ (all the equalities taken modulo $7$).

Also $$3^{1000}=(3^6)^{166}\cdot 3^4= 1 \cdot 4 = 4$$(all the equalities taken modulo $7$).

Now if we note that $10^6=1$ (modulo 7) the expression of $3^{1000}$ in base $10^6$ reads (modulo 7)
$$ 4=b_0+b_1+ \cdots +b_{79}$$

So we can assert that the sum of digits of $3^{1000}$ in base one milion gives a remainder of $4$ when divided by $7$.

Another partial result comes from the decimal expansion read modulo 7:

$$3^{1000}= a_0+ a_1 \cdot 10 + \cdots +a_{477} \cdot 10^{477} =1 = a_0+3 a_1+ 2a_2 + 6 a_3 + 4 a_4 + 5 a_ 5 + \cdots $$

So, given that $a_0=1$ we can say that this particular linear combination of the remaining digits is divisible by $7$.

Comment: I remember to have calculated $500$ digits for $3^{1000}$ two days ago. Was I wrong?

Comment: In base $10^6$ there are $10^6$ "digits".....($10^{18}$ is written $1000$ so is it $0+0+0+1\equiv4\pmod 7$?

Comment: I don't understand your last claim "given $a_0 = 1$, we can say... divisible by $7$".

Comment: To @achillehui: We know that the first digit of $3^{1000}$ is $1$ so $ a_1+ 2a_2 + 6 a_3 + 4 a_4 + 5 a_ 5 + \cdots=0$ modulo $7$

Comment: @ArundoDonax oh, I see what you mean now.

Comment: @ArundoDonax thank you very much it's extremely intersting

Comment: In the last equation you write 3^1000 = ... = 1 = ..., may I assume that this is an error? Actually, 3^1000 = 9^500 == 2^(498+2) = 8^(498/3) * 2^2 == 4 (mod 7). It can't be =1 and =4 ....

Answer (score 2):

Base-$10$ digit sums mod $7$ are, unfortunately, not particularly nicely behaved.
The first hundred $n$ for which the sum of digits of $3^n$ is divisible by $7$ are
$$ 25, 26, 30, 32, 47, 58, 79, 81, 87, 89, 102, 123, 141, 144, 145, 151, 164, 176, 178, 193, 201, 227, 239, 242, 257, 264, 282, 289, 300, 306, 319, 324, 329, 335, 336, 338, 348, 351, 358, 365, 395, 403, 437, 441, 450, 460, 468, 484, 489, 492, 495, 517, 518, 541, 542, 544, 554, 555, 563, 565, 570, 580, 587, 597, 601, 610, 617, 618, 620, 638, 639, 655, 659, 663, 671, 695, 720, 721, 745, 748, 755, 757, 772, 774, 781, 783, 789, 790, 797, 800, 805, 809, 813, 822, 826, 828, 841, 844, 850, 859$$
I don't see any pattern here.

Comment: I would like so much to have your methods for numerical calculation.....Regards.

Comment: @Piquito It's very easy in Maple: convert(convert(3^n, base, 10), \`+\`);

Comment: Robert, how far can you push your calculations, I would like to see as many $n$ as possible.?

Comment: For example, $3^{1000000}$ took about $50$ seconds on my computer: the sum is $2146509$, which is not divisible by $7$.

Comment: We have $$ds_{10} (3^{12348})=26397$$ Here both an exponent and the resull are divisible by 7. Maybe not important, just mentioning in case you also study this sequence and seek for curiosities.

Comment: Can you find more examples such as this mine?

Comment: @Robert Israel: Is really wonderful what you tell to A. de Paladin. I do not know these wonders computing. Thanks for your reply.  (I think the only hope for this problem is to arrive to get a formation law for multiplication by $3$ of the successive  powers of $3$. The problem is that randomly this multiplication can be made for  ten digits with the known consequences  when  $3\cdot a\gt 10$).

Comment: I noticed something that does not quite fit models.of random-digit-behavior.

Comment: Robert, do you want to send me an e-mail in which there are as many as possible $n$`s? Say, 10000, or so. I noticed something but cannot conjecture it because I need more numbers.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A292931](https://oeis.org/A292931).  You can download a table of the first $10000$ terms there.