# Does this sequence ever become monotone?

Tags: sequences-and-series

While I was trying to do at least some progress having to do with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433244/sum-of-digits-of-31000?newsletter=1&nlcode=812219%7cf4fc) awesome question I calculated digit sum in base $10$ of $3^a$ for $a=1,2,...,25$ and the pattern goes like this:

$3,9,9,9,9,18,18,18,27,27,27,18,27,45,36,27,27,45,36,45,27,45,54,54,63...$

Since numbers grow with every next step the digit sum could be monotone after some $3^{n_0}$ but I doubt that this is the case, that is, I believe that this sequence never becomes monotone, that is, that there is sequence $n_i \in \mathbb N$ such that $ds_{10}(3^{n_i+1})>ds_{10}(3^{n_i})$.

> Is it true that this sequence of digit sums never becomes monotone?

Answer (score 1):

A proof of this conjecture is probably out of reach, but the fact that the digit sum of $3^{10^4}$ is $21\ 663$ and the digit sum of $3^{10^4+1}$ is $21\ 267$, so smaller, clearly indicates it. I will search even larger counterexamples for monotony.

UPDATE :

digit sum of $3^{10^7}$  is $\color \red {\ \ \ \ \ 21\ 469\ 896}$

digit sum of $3^{10^7+1}$ is $\color\green {\ \ 21\ 461\ 742}$

so still no monotony.

Comment: I think that this should not be out of reach, some clever application of known theorems and results about digit sums and "how multiplication of $3^a$ with $3$ approximately alters digit sum" could settle this.

Comment: digitsum of $3^{10^5+2}$ is $215\ 064$ and digitsum of $3^{10^5+3}$ is $214\ 623$

Comment: I upvoted since you show interest and are doing actual computations. +1 for the effort.

Comment: digitsum of $3^{10^6+1}$ is $2\ 150\ 487$ and digitsum of $3^{10^6+2}$ is $2\ 146\ 977$

Comment: By looking at the ratios $\dfrac {215064}{214623}$ and $\dfrac {2150487}{2146977}$ it seems that the limiting behavior of these counterexamples tends to $1$ which shows that this could be hard, at least for an amateur like me.

Comment: It is obvious that it must tend to 1, is it?

Comment: Seems to be the case, but I have no idea for a proof , but I think this can be proven somehow.

Comment: You can add these results from the comments and the values of ratios in an edit of your answer, if only just to be more readable and elegant. And to improve the answer.

Comment: @Antoine I added a particular large counterexample to my answer

Comment: I would add both these two from the comments and all three ratios, because it looks like there is some monotony in these ratios.

Comment: @Antoine Most of the digits of the third powers (except the few last digits) behave like a purely random sequence. Taking the average of the digits of a large power of $3$ shows that it is very near $4.5$ (the theoretical value, if we omit the first digit which can't be $0$). Therefore, it is no surprise that the ratio tends to $1$ and the fluctuations of the digit-sum seem to prevent an eventually monotonic sequence, but such heuristics are no proof.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The sum-of-digits function is itself non-monotonic (https://oeis.org/A007953). In the range $[10^k,10^{k+1})$ it varies from $1$ to $9k$, while there are on average $2.0959\cdots$ powers of $3$ that fall in that range, at somewhat "random" positions.

[image]